# BulkInsert entities with ComplexType

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

How to insert many entities with a ComplexType in a timely fashion?

Consider the following:

```
public class Entity {
  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Address {
  [ColumnName("Street")]
  public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I tried [SqlBulkTools](https://github.com/gtaylor44/SqlBulkTools) which ignores nested properties. Both `.CustomColumnMapping(x => x.Address.Street, "Street")` and `.AddColumn(x => x.Address.Street)` didn't crash but didn't actually do anything either.

I also tried `EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6` which is confused by the ComplexTypes and crashes.

Doing the inserts one by one takes a very long time, even with ValidateOnSaveEnabled and AutoDetectChangesEnabled turned off. Creating new contexts and playing with the amount of `DbContext.SaveChanges()` didn't help either.

Comment: Just my opinion: I don't like any of the BulkInsert Tools coming around EF6. There's no much support and nobody guarantee that they will work with further versions of EF. (And Data components are just too core to take that risk). so whenever I want to Bulk things. I use old good plain ADO.NET SqlBulkCopy even if it's lead to a more unelegant solution.

Comment: The most efficent way to run SQL in .Net is ADO.Net. **Nothing** will beat this for performance. So if you want performance use ADO.Net SqlBulkCopy (as mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that using **Entity Framework Extended Library**.

Just an example:

```
//update all Entities with Street of MyStreet to Street of YourStreet
context.Entities 
    .Where(t => t.Address.Street == "MyStreet")
    .Update(t => new Entity { t.Address.Street = "YourStreet" });
```

Here is the Link : [**Entity Framework Extended Library**](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended)

Comment: He is asking for bulk inserting. This library does not offer this feature.

Answer (score -2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows Bulk Inserting (With Complex Type) but also all other bulk operations.

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

Example

```
// Bulk Insert
context.BulkInsert(complexTypeEntities);

// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);
```

The library support all kind of inheritance and association, however, the library is not free.